# Como pronunciar o apelido Houaiss?

Tags: pronúncia

Sendo o dicionário de Antônio Houaiss uma grande referência na Lusofonia, eu, como falante da variante europeia da Língua não sei pronunciar o seu apelido.

Podem facultar-me alguma referência áudio? Ou o apelido escrito com alfabeto fonético?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo fontes brasileiras e portuguesas, o sobrenome Houaiss é pronunciado, em português, "uáiss" - ou, em representação técnica, [/ 'wajs /] ou [/ u'ajs /], no Alfabeto Fonético Internacional, em que o símbolo [w] corresponde ao som 'u' de 'quase' e o símbolo [u] ao 'u' da palavra 'nua', enquanto [aj] se assemelha ao 'ai' de 'caixa' e o símbolo [s] ao 'ss' de 'massa'. O símbolo [‘] precede o fonema tônico da palavra.

in: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B4nio_Houaiss

Comment: Sempre li com a fonética inglesa ("rauweis"), mas nunca pensei que na verdade seria pronunciado com a do português. :p